# i use this janus Code but my Export File is 0 byte

Tags: janus

i use this Code but my Export File is 0 byte

```
 saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (saveFileDialog1.FileName != "")
        {
            System.IO.FileStream st = new System.IO.FileStream(saveFileDialog1.FileName, System.IO.FileMode.Create);
            this.gridEXExporter1.ExportMode = Janus.Windows.GridEX.ExportMode.AllRows;
            gridEXExporter1.GridEX = gridEX1;
            gridEXExporter1.Export(st);
            st.Close();
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, It works fine for me:

```
    if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(saveFileDialog.FileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            gridEXExporter.Export(fs);
        }
    }
```